# How can I assign values to radio buttons with the forms api?

Tags: forms

I made radio buttons with the forms api using this code:

```
"sex" => array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => t('Sex'),
        '#options' => array(t('M'), t('F')),
)
```

It works perfectly, but instead of storing an M or an F in the database, it stores a 0 or a 1. How can I decide what value is stored for each option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keys of the array set as `#options` determine the values and the values determine the labels.

In other words: The example in my question uses a regular array `array(t('M'), t('F'))` which, behind the scenes, is an associative array using non-negative integers as keys (same as `array(0=>t('M'), 1=>t('F'))`. Since the radio buttons use these keys to know what to store in the database, the solution is simply to change them: `array('M'=>t('M'), 'F'=>t('F'))`.